# How to combine more (at least three) metrics and count result

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I need to combine three existing metrics (kube_pod_labels, kube_namespace_labels and kube_pod_status_phase). The fields I need to use are:

- kube_namespace_labels: namespace, team
- kube_pod_labels: pod, namespace, application, *team* (have to be replaced by kube_namespace_labels.team value)
- kube_pod_status_phase: pod, namespace, phase

I need to get running pods (kube_pod_status_phase) for given application (kube_pod_labels) and count by namespace's team (kube_namespace_labels).

The query which is in my mind is like this: `count (kube_pod_labels{application=~"..."} * on(pod) group_left(team) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"} * on(namespace) group_left(team) kube_namespace_labels{team=~"..."})) by (team)`, where application and team are multiselects (well also phase can be, but it's not necessary). But this one doesn't work. It return values, but changing phase still returns same counts, which is not correct.

- the Grafana version is 9.30;
- the problem is that the query `kube_pod_labels{application=~"..."} * on(pod) group_left(team) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"} * on(namespace) group_left(team) kube_namespace_labels{team=~"..."})` returns wrong results.

Comment: The easiest way here will be for you to debug your query yourself. Remove `count by` and check output. Your question is not very clear in what is your problem, but you probably need to use `sum` instead of `count`, because `kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"}` still returns vectors even if pod is stopped, it's just that values in those vectors are zeroes.

Comment: Hi, the 'joins' part doesn't work correctly, I've played with it. It returns same values for each phase (same sets for Running, Failing, etc.; the numbers should differ, I've checked it in Kubernetes). An the Grafana version is 9.30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
sum by (team) (
    kube_pod_labels{application=~"..."}
    * on(pod, namespace) group_left(team)
    (
        kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"}
            * on(namespace) group_left(team)
            kube_namespace_labels{team=~"..."}
    )
)
```

Have to use `sum` instead of `count` and `kube_namespace_labels` have to use only `namespace`.